# why a key-value pairs with array as key can be found in a map using the get method?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, equals

Must say before all that my basic knowledge comes from java and not js.
I have the following map:

```
const myMap = new Map();
myMap.set([1,2], 'Test');
myMap.get([1,2]// return undefined
```

can't understand why the last line of code doesn't return *'Test'*.
in java the key is being checked using **equals** method, how does js checks for equality?
I'm not looking for the solution that will return 'Test', only the explantion why it is not return 'Test' for this specific code?

Comment: `[1,2] !== [1,2]`.

Comment: why? they are both the same type and the same values!!!

Comment: How precisely a map does equality on keys can be read on the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Key_equality) or the spec. For why the above holds, because with reference equality, they are two separate instances of an array - the same values inside, but still two.

Comment: i have checked and [1,2] == [1,2] also return false. It is super not understandable

Comment: There are hundreds of articles that explain this in detail and with many examples, better than i can and/or would be willing to repeat in a comment - maybe someone has a link to a good dupe target, or a tutorial.